# Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition during execution plan on

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, temp-tables, sql-execution-plan, global-temp-tables

Currently we are facing the issue only when we are executing a stored procedure keeping the **Include Actual Execution Plan - ON**. Otherwise the stored procedure is executing fine and returning results as expected.
What would be the reason for this kind of behavior?

I have already went through this links but the error is different here as it only occurs when we have kept the **Include Actual Execution Plan - ON**.
[Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20372361/sql-server-column-name-or-number-of-supplied-values-does-not-match-table-defini)
[Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1152932/column-name-or-number-of-supplied-values-does-not-match-table-definition)

Sample code (PROC1) -

```
CREATE PROCEDURE PROC1 (blah blah blah)
AS
BEGIN
 BEGIN TRY
 -------------
 code
 --------------
 -----issue code-----
 INSERT INTO #temptable (col1,col2,.....)
 EXECUTE PROC2
 -------------
 code
 --------------
 END TRY
 BEGIN CATCH
  ---------
  RAISERROR(............); 
 END CATCH
END
```

Sample code (PROC2) -

```
CREATE PROCEDURE PROC2
BEGIN
 BEGIN TRY
 ---------------
 code
 ---------------
 SELECT COL1,COL2,COL3,..... FROM #innersptemptable
 END TRY
 BEGIN CATCH
 --------------------
 RAISERROR();
 --------------------
 END CATCH
END
```

**Note:** `PROC2` returns exact same number of columns which we have taken care while inserting into `#temptable`

Do let me know if any further information is required.

**Environment -**

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.2000.8 (X64) 
Feb 20 2014 20:04:26 
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)
```

**Edit1:**  When the error occurs in PROC1 and it is captured, it is noted that the `ERROR_PROCEDURE()` return the value of PROC2 but again PROC2 runs fine and gives results as expected with and without the **Include Actual Execution Plan** kept **ON**.

**Edit2:** When we replaced local temp table with global temp table (the temp table I am talking about is used to pass the result set from PROC2) inside PROC2 then the execution of PROC1 happened successfully.

**Edit3:** When we removed the TRY-CATCH block from the inner sp (PROC2) and executed the PROC1 keeping **Include Actual Execution Plan - ON** no errors were reported and execution was completed successfully.
[image: Error Description]

Comment: how is table #temptable created in the Proc1 SP ?

Comment: Like below - 

`IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temptable') IS NOT NULL
   BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #temptable;
   END


        CREATE TABLE #temptable (
col1 datatype,
col2 datatype,
-----------------
-----------------
)`