# C# .net winforms data insert error

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace crudwithlogin
{
    public partial class student_registration : Form
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Android\Documents\Data.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");

        public student_registration()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void student_registration_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text = "You are logged in as "+((Form)this.MdiParent).Controls["label1"].Text;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "insert into student values ('" 
                                                   + textBox1.Text 
                                                   + "','" 
                                                   + textBox2.Text 
                                                   + "''" 
                                                   + dateTimePicker2.Value.ToString() 
                                                   + "','" 
                                                   + textBox4.Text 
                                                   + "','" 
                                                   + comboBox2.Text 
                                                   + "','" 
                                                   + textBox6.Text 
                                                   + "','" 
                                                   + dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString() 
                                                   + "')";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Data Added Successfully. ");
        }
    }
}
```

Hello Experts I am creating a Windows forms app using C#, I am trying to 
insert data into a database but I am getting an error of values and columns do not match even though I am entering the right value for right attribute.

I have 8 attributes (id with auto increment), and for the remaining 7 columns I am entering 7 values but I get error of value not match.

Please help me solve this problem. I have attached the code and screenshots of problem

Error I get is shown here:

[image]

Database schema screenshot is here

[image]

Comment: Please let me know if your issue hasn't resolved

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sql server: Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20372361/sql-server-column-name-or-number-of-supplied-values-does-not-match-table-defini)

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
('" + textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text + "''" + dateTimePicker2.Value.ToString() + "','" 
//missed , ------------------------------------^
```

Also use Command.Parameters in future and you will avoid problems like this ! Also you will be protected from `SqlInjection`. Here example how to define your params.

```
 SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
 cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
 cmd.CommandText = @"insert into TableNameFromDB values (@ID, @Title)";
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", yourIDValue);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Title", yourTitleValue);
 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
 conn.Close();
```

Also don't share one connection in your app, use multiple connections. Connection pool is your friend. Check what is using block and use it for auto disposing of your IDisposable objects( example: `SqlConnection`).

Comment: what will i write place of 'yourIDValue' ? textbox1.text ?

Answer (score 0):

Carefully look your insert query there is a **,** (coma)missing.  Could you please correct your query as following:

```
"insert into student values ('" + textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text + "','" + dateTimePicker2.Value.ToString() + "','" + textBox4.Text + "','" + comboBox2.Text + "','" + textBox6.Text + "','" + dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString() + "')";
```

If yet not works then may be problem with database structure and corresponding values.

Comment: Welcome@Precious Pari

Comment: can you tell me which database should i use for stand alone application which i could install on any other pc without database installation

Comment: and if i want to create point of sale app then should i go with window form or wpf ?